# Need query to join table on column with comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Table1

| ID | Notes | ReasonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | [11,12] |
| 2 | Test2 | [13,14] |

Table 2

| Reasonid | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Other1 |
| 12 | Other2 |
| 13 | Other3 |
| 14 | Other4 |

Result should look like this, where `Notes` column from `Table1` should concat with `Name` column from `Table2`.

| ID | Final_Notes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1,Other1,Other2 |
| 2 | Test2,Other3,Other4 |

Comment: Do you see why storing the data this way is more trouble than it’s worth?

Comment: That's requirement :-D

Comment: Well, sure, everything everyone builds came from requirements. But that doesn't make them _good_ requirements, or prevent them from being something you talk about the next time you meet with the people who created these requirements. They're using a relational database but treating it like a text file.

Comment: A good developer knows when the business "requirements" and the implementation requirements are vastly different, @zzstar . Sure, *maybe* the business "requires" the data to be **presented** in a delimited fashion, but that doesn't mean the data should be *stored* in a delimited fashion; it should be normalised and then the data *presented* using string aggregation.

Comment: When you have such requirement  then you badly need Split String UDF or use InBuilt string_split

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may try to parse the `ReasonID` column as JSON, use an appropriate `JOIN` and then aggregate with `STRING_AGG()`.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Table1
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'Test1', '[11,12]'),
   (2, 'Test2', '[13,14]')
) t (ID, Notes, ReasonID)

SELECT *
INTO Table2
FROM (VALUES
   (11, 'Other1'),
   (12, 'Other2'),
   (13, 'Other3'),
   (14, 'Other4')
) t (ReasonID, Name)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   FinalNotes = CONCAT(
      Notes,
      ',',
      (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.Name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key]))
      FROM OPENJSON(ReasonID) j
      -- Important, JOIN with possible implicit conversion
      JOIN Table2 t2 ON j.[value] = t2.ReasonID
      )
   )
FROM Table1
```

Result:

| ID | FinalNotes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1,Other1,Other2 |
| 2 | Test2,Other3,Other4 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b567740ffe7f81aa338c098f082fa5f1)

Comment: I m not using SQL Server 2014 version not 2017

Comment: All the more reason to normalise your data then, @zzstar , or if you "must" use denormalised and JSON data, then get the business to fork out the costs for you to be able to use it in the back end with a fully supported version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

It is using the following:

- XML/XQuery to tokenize comma separated list of values.
- `FOR XML PATH` to compose *FinalNotes* comma separated list.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT, Notes VARCHAR(60), ReasonID VARCHAR(60));
INSERT INTO @Table1(ID, Notes, ReasonID) VALUES 
(1, 'Test1', '[11,12]'), 
(2, 'Test2', '[13,14]');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(Reasonid INT, Name VARCHAR(60));
INSERT INTO @Table2(Reasonid, Name) VALUES 
(11, 'Other1'), 
(12, 'Other2'), 
(13, 'Other3'), 
(14, 'Other4');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, Notes, Name
    FROM @Table1 AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ReasonID,'[',''),']',''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t2(x)
        INNER JOIN @Table2 AS t3 ON t3.Reasonid = x.value('.', 'INT')
)
SELECT ID, CONCAT(Notes
    , (SELECT @separator + c.Name AS [text()]
       FROM rs AS c
       WHERE c.ID = p.ID
       FOR XML PATH(''))) AS FinalNotes
FROM rs AS p
GROUP BY ID, Notes;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------+
| ID |     FinalNotes      |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | Test1,Other1,Other2 |
|  2 | Test2,Other3,Other4 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SUBSTRING(string, 2, LEN(string)-2)`   for deleting `[]`  and `Parsename` to split based on comma and `join` and `concat` as follows

Your data

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  Notes VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
  ReasonID VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Table1(ID, Notes, ReasonID) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Test1', '[11,12]'), 
  (2, 'Test2', '[13,14]');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
  Reasonid INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  Name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Table2(Reasonid, Name) 
VALUES 
  (11, 'Other1'), 
  (12, 'Other2'), 
  (13, 'Other3'), 
  (14, 'Other4');
```

your query

```
SELECT id,
       Concat(notes, ',', T2.name, ',', T3.name) FinalNotes
FROM  (SELECT id,
              notes,
              Parsename(Replace(SUBSTRING(ReasonID, 2, LEN(ReasonID)-2), ',', '.'), 2) R1,
              Parsename(Replace(SUBSTRING(ReasonID, 2, LEN(ReasonID)-2), ',', '.'), 1) R2
       FROM   @table1) T1
      join @table2 T2
        ON T1.R1 = T2.reasonid
      join @table2 T3
        ON T1.R2 = T3.reasonid
```

by using XML

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t -- temporary table
  select t1.ID,t1.Notes, Name into #t -- temporary table
  from 
(
SELECT A.ID,a.Notes,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT ID, Notes, 
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ReasonID, 2, LEN(ReasonID)-2)  , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @Table1) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) t1 
     join @Table2 t2 on t1.String=t2.Reasonid
---XML Path
SELECT  ID,concat(notes,',',
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(name AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM #t t1
         WHERE t1.ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ')) FinalNotes
FROM #t t
GROUP BY ID,notes
```

Comment: `TRIM()` is not available in SQL Server 2014, also `PARSENAME()` might not be safe to trust, we don't know how long those reason lists can be.

Comment: I have edit my answer and use substring

Comment: The `PARSENAME()` function can handle just up to 4 tokens.

Comment: Now its working fine. How to handle extra comma when notes values in blank

Comment: use more join with @table2  and use Concat(notes, ',', T2.name, ',', T3.name, ',', T4.name,) or use XML path query